# Export Flat File based on the each SQL statement in the table and destination

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I'm still new in SSIS,

Now I can read the SQLStatement, FileName, and FileLocation based on this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sUQNbltHP-U)

But I'm facing the problems when export the flat file base on the File Location in SQL Table.

[image]

You can check my [sample package](https://github.com/cheahengsoon/SSISPackage). Besides, the following screenshot shows the SQL table structure where information is stored:

**Different FileName, Different File Location and different SQL Command**

[image]

Comment: What is wrong with a cursor?

Comment: @Alex the cursor cant execute in SSIS Package

Comment: Do you get error messages?

Comment: @Alex how to export with flat file based on the each command in the table?

Comment: @EngSoonCheah I guess you shouldn't use the Execute SQL Task but a DataFlow task. There you can specify a flatfile destination. However, you will have to use an expression in order to set the filename dynamically - otherwise you will overwrite the file in each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Honestly, storing SQL statements, that need to be executed, in a table seems like a concern unto itself, unless you have very good validation processes on the queries being entered. Otherwise this could easily open you up to injection attacks, depending on who (or what) can enter statements into this table.

Answer (score 3):

#### Important Note

Storing SQL Commands and file locations within databases and using them within a dynamic data import process is not recommended from a security perspective.

#### TLDR

You must add a Data Flow Task that contains an OLE DB Source and Flat File Destination configured to read from the SSIS variables.

#### Details

1. First, make sure that you used the variables mapping in the for-each loop container to retrieve all information about the source (SQL command) and destination (Flat file path and configuration).

- [Looping Through a ResultSet with the ForEach Loop](https://blog.pragmaticworks.com/looping-through-a-result-set-with-the-foreach-loop)

2. Next, you should add a Flat File connection manager (for the destination) and configure the connection string to read from the `[File Location]` and `[File Name]` variables.

- [SSIS: Dynamic File Name for Flat File Destination](http://rajeevdotnet.blogspot.com/2018/12/ssis-dynamic-file-name-for-flat-file.html)
- [Dynamic Flat File Connections in SQL Server Integration Services](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1084/dynamic-flat-file-connections-in-sql-server-integration-services/)

3. Third step is to add a Data Flow Task within the Foreach loop container, where you should add an OLE DB Source and a Flat File Destination.
4. Set the OLE DB Source "Data Access Mode" to `SQL Command from variable` and select the variable you have mapped to the `SQL Command` column.
5. Configure the Flat File Destination to use the Flat File Connection Manager created previously.

---

#### Side Note

Check the following detailed article. It explains a very similar case:

- [Implementing Foreach Looping Logic in SSIS](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/ssis/implementing-foreach-looping-logic-in-ssis/)

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to your question, but a simplification. A view on the table that provides the complete bcp statement would avoid a lot of parameters. (Can @@Servername be the instance?) Then SSIS can query the view and run each command.

Edit: added a bcp to add column names to the file

```
SELECT 
    'bcp "SELECT name from sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(''' 
        + SUBSTRING(@SqlCommand, CHARINDEX(' FROM', @SqlCommand) + 6, 8000) + ''')' 
        + '" queryout " + FileLocation + '\' + FileName + '" '
        + '-S"' + @@SERVERNAME + '" -d"' + DatabaseName + '" -t, -c -T' 
        as [BcpCmdColumnNames],
    'bcp "' + SqlCommand + '" queryout " + FileLocation + '\' + FileName + '" '
        + '-S"' + @@SERVERNAME + '" -d"' + DatabaseName + '" -t, -c -T' 
        as [BcpCmdTableData]
FROM dbo.Falina_Config
```

I might also avoid SSIS and use a Job Step running PowerShell.exe.  Here is a possible PowerShell script using DBATools. (You can use any alternate to do the query without DBATools.)

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6172/execute-powershell-script-from-ssis-package/

https://dbatools.io/

Edit: Added query for column names

```
param( 
    [string] $instance = 'myinstance', 
    [string] $dbname = 'mydatabase'
) 

$queryExtracts = 'select DatabaseName, SqlCommand, FileLocation, FileName from dbo.Falina_Config'

$extracts = Invoke-DbaQuery -SqlInstance $instance -Database $dbname -Query $query -CommandType Text | 
    select DatabaseName, SqlCommand, FileLocation, FileName

foreach ($extract in $extracts) {

    $fileLocation = $extract.FileLocation
    $fileName = $extract.FileName

    $file = Join-Path $fileLocation $fileName
    
    $databaseName = $extract.DatabaseName
    #$queryColumnNames = "select name from sys.columns where object_id = OBJECT_ID('[$($extract.TableSchema)].[$($extract.TableName)]')"
    #$queryTableData = "select * from [$($extract.TableSchema)].[$($extract.TableName)]" # this might be safer
    $querySqlCommand = $extract.SqlCommand 

    #bcp "$queryColumnNames" queryout "$fileName" -S"$instance" -d"$databaseName" --% -t, -c -T
    #bcp "$queryTableData" queryout "$fileName" -S"$instance" -d"$databaseName" --% -t, -c -T
    bcp "$querySqlCommand" queryout "$fileName" -S"$instance" -d"$databaseName" --% -t, -c -T

}
```

The --% stops PowerShell from parsing or replacing the stuff in the rest of the line. For example, it would not like the comma.

Warning, I did not test any of this so expect it to require modification. It would be amazing if I got the quoted quotes right.

Comment: the bcp command , how to include the table header automatically?

Comment: You can run two bcp commands per table. The first query generates one record of the column names from sys.columns.  I'll edit the post.

Comment: I just noticed the SQLCommand is a select on the configuration table. I assumed there would be one SQLCommand for each table to extract. For the header, the table name and columns are needed. Provide them as columns in the table or insure you can parse them from SqlCommand.

Answer (score 1):

Your biggest challenge using SSIS for this is that (I assume) your differing SQL statements are going to return differing sets of columns. SSIS Data Flows and Flat File Destinations do not support dynamic columns, in fact they are very rigid.

So instead I would configure the Execute SQL Task to return a Result Set into a variable, then connect a Script task inside your Loop.  The Script would need to loop over the Result Set variable's rows and columns, and write them out to the variable destination file.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use Script Task
2. Create a Variable.
3. Enter the variable to the ReadOnlyVariables: User::FileDelimiter,User::FileExtension,User::LogFolder,User::SQLStatement

[image]

its also include the script at the back end

```
public void Main()
        {
            string datetime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
            try
            {

                //Declare Variables
                string SQLStatement = Dts.Variables["User::SQLStatement"].Value.ToString();
                string FileDelimiter = Dts.Variables["User::FileDelimiter"].Value.ToString();
                string FileExtension = Dts.Variables["User::FileExtension"].Value.ToString();



                //USE ADO.NET Connection from SSIS Package to get data from table
                SqlConnection myADONETConnection = new SqlConnection();
                myADONETConnection = (SqlConnection)(Dts.Connections["DBConn"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction) as SqlConnection);


                //Read list of Tables with Schema from Database
                string query = "SELECT FilesName,FileDestination,SQLStatement FROM "+ SQLStatement;

                //MessageBox.Show(query.ToString());
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, myADONETConnection);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());

                //Loop through datatable(dt) that has schema and table names
                foreach (DataRow dt_row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    string FileName = "";
                    string FileDestination = "";
                    string TableName = "";
                    object[] array = dt_row.ItemArray;
                    FileName = array[0].ToString();
                    FileDestination = array[1].ToString();
                    TableName = array[2].ToString();

                    string FileFullPath = FileDestination + FileName; //DestinationFolder + "\\" + SchemaName + "_" + TableName + "_" + datetime + FileExtension;

                    //Get the data for a table into data table 
                    string data_query = TableName; //"SELECT * FROM [" + SchemaName + "].[" + TableName + "]";
                    SqlCommand data_cmd = new SqlCommand(data_query, myADONETConnection);
                    DataTable d_table = new DataTable();
                    d_table.Load(data_cmd.ExecuteReader());

                    StreamWriter sw = null;
                    sw = new StreamWriter(FileFullPath, false);

                    // Write the Header Row to File
                    int ColumnCount = d_table.Columns.Count;
                    for (int ic = 0; ic < ColumnCount; ic++)
                    {
                        sw.Write(d_table.Columns[ic]);
                        if (ic < ColumnCount - 1)
                        {
                            sw.Write(FileDelimiter);
                        }
                    }
                    sw.Write(sw.NewLine);

                    // Write All Rows to the File
                    foreach (DataRow dr in d_table.Rows)
                    {
                        for (int ir = 0; ir < ColumnCount; ir++)
                        {
                            if (!Convert.IsDBNull(dr[ir]))
                            {
                                sw.Write(dr[ir].ToString());
                            }
                            if (ir < ColumnCount - 1)
                            {
                                sw.Write(FileDelimiter);
                            }
                        }
                        sw.Write(sw.NewLine);

                    }

                    sw.Close();

                    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
                }

            }

            catch (Exception exception)
            {

                // Create Log File for Errors
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(Dts.Variables["User::LogFolder"].Value.ToString() + "\\" +
                    "ErrorLog_" + datetime + ".log"))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(exception.ToString());
                    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;


                }
            }
        }
```