# Export SQL Query output using powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, t-sql

I am fairly new to Powershell and need some guidance on exporting SQL server query output.

We are having a very large table from which we want to export data. The size is huge so data will be extracted based on date ranges we are going to give. So for multiple date ranges we will be exporting multiple csv files. As part of this  we will be running some queries with joins between tables using the date ranges and the output will be exported. I have tried using inbuilt functionality BCP of SQL server but the output does not contain any headers and formatting is also an issue. The table is very huge and large number of columns that is around 500+ so using UNION for displaying headers is not an option using BCP. The query will be used by people not so familiar with SQL so GUI also not recommended. Hence wanted to check if we can do this using powershell.
Below is the kind of the query i have created in SQL:

```
declare @date1 nchar(8)
declare @date2 nchar(8)
DECLARE @ExportFolderName NVARCHAR(90);
DECLARE @ExportFileName NVARCHAR(90);
Declare @db_name nvarchar(90)
--create temporary table
create table ##temp(
USER bigint,
USER_ID nvarchar(100)
);
--insert date ranges as required
Create table #dates(todate nchar(8), fromdate nchar(8))
insert into #dates values('20200501','20200601')
insert into #dates values('20200602','20200701')
insert into #dates values('20200702','20200801')
insert into #dates values('20200802','20200901')
select @db_name=db_name();
DECLARE database_cursor CURSOR FOR 
select todate,fromdate from #dates
OPEN database_cursor 
FETCH NEXT FROM database_cursor INTO @Date1,@date2
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN 
SET @ExportFolderName = 'C:\test\';
SET @ExportFileName = @ExportFolderName + @db_name+'_logs_' + RTRIM(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), @date2,112)) + '.csv';
insert into ##temp
(USER, USER_ID)
(
**************
);
DECLARE @SqlStatement nvarchar(1000)
DECLARE @BcpStatement nvarchar(1000)
SET @SqlStatement = 'select * from dbo.logs E with (nolock) inner join ##temp U on E.USER=U.USER  and E.USER_ID COLLATE =U.USER_ID where E.DATE1 >= '''+@date1+''' and E.DATE1 < '''+@date2+''' order by event_id'
--print @sqlstatement
SET @BcpStatement = 'bcp "' + @SqlStatement + '" queryout "' + @ExportFileName + '" -c -S SERVER -d DAtabase -U Login -P PWD'
exec master..xp_cmdshell @BcpStatement
--print @bcpstatement
  FETCH NEXT FROM database_cursor INTO @Date1,@date2 
END 
CLOSE database_cursor 
DEALLOCATE database_cursor 
drop table ##temp
drop table #dates
```

I believe we have something like below to export data from a .sql file:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance ServerName -Database master -Username "user" -Password "pwd" -InputFile "C:\powershell\test.sql" | Out-File -FilePath "C:\powershell\test_(based on date).csv"
```

But the issue is passing date parameters to the query inside the .sql file. Could someone please give me any pointers on how to achieve this.

Comment: There are a couple of ways to handle this, but let me first ask you, whether you are planning to execute the above command via job or directly from PowerShell console?

Comment: Plan is to run it via console.

Comment: Rather than `Out-File` you might want to look into `Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation`.

Comment: You can use bcp to write the header.  A second bcp can then write the data. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65138404/export-flat-file-based-on-the-each-sql-statement-in-the-table-and-destination/65208245#65208245

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, thanks, I will take a look into that.

Answer (score 0):

**Not the cleanest of solutions, but should suffice the need -**

One way of doing this would be creating a stored procedure with input parameter and passing the date parameters as PowerShell variables.

For example -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ExportDataFromLargeTable @date1 nchar(8),  @date2 nchar(8)
AS
DECLARE @ExportFolderName NVARCHAR(90);
DECLARE @ExportFileName NVARCHAR(90);
.
.
/*Rest of the code goes here*/
.
.
GO
```

After the SP is created, you can use the below PowerShell code to execute the above procedure -

```
$Server = 'YourServerName'
$Database = 'YourDatabaseName'
$FirstDate = 'WhicheverFormatDate1IsIn'
$SecondDate = 'WhicheverFormatDate2IsIn'
$Query = "EXEC ExportDataFromLargeTable '$($FirstDate)', '$($SecondDate)'"
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $Query -ServerInstance $Server -Database $Database | Export-Csv "C:\powershell\test_(based on date).csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Pass `FirstDate` followed by `SecondDate` because the order of passing parameters will affect the output.

Comment: Thanks, however cannot make any changes in prod server. Also there will be multiple date ranges so i think have to add loop as well.

Comment: In that case, replace all `@date1` and `@date2` in your query, **EXCEPT THE DECLARATION PART**, with a PowerShell variable, say $Date1 and $Date2. Instead of an SP, your `$Query` now becomes the one which you have originally mentioned in the question. After that run the same `Invoke-Sqlcmd` command. You can definitely loop the date ranges with PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

Found below solution:

```
$DBScriptFile = "C:\Log\QUERY.sql"  #enter file path for .sql file
$outputpath="C:\log\" #Enter output path
$client="Client" # enter client name
$table="Table_name"
$sqlParameters =(("startdate='20191201'", "enddate='20191209'") ,("startdate='20191209'", "enddate='20191231'"),("startdate='20200101'", "enddate='20200201'"))
$count=1
foreach($i in $sqlParameters)
{
$filename=$outputpath+$client+"_"+$table +"_" + $count +".csv"

Invoke-Sqlcmd  ServerName -Database master -Username "user" -Password "pwd"   -InputFile $DBScriptFile -Variable $i |export-csv -path $filename -NoTypeInformation
$count=$count+1
}
```

We need to add $(startdate) & $(enddate) in SQL script file for arguments.