# Calling stored procedure with multiple parameters in powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, stored-procedures

I have an stored procedure with many parameters:

```
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[SQLdatabase]
(
    @operation nvarchar(10) = null,
    @mode nvarchar(10) = 'smart',
    @LogToTable bit = 0
) As .....(it's a long procedure)
```

And want to call the SProcedure in Powershell code.In the beginning of the code I've called the parameters, if I need to define them in code?

```
$operation  = 'index'
$mode       = 'smart'
$LogToTable = $true
```

Don't know how to complete the below code and call parameters correctly.

```
$sqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=$dataSource;Initial Catalog=$database;Integrated Security=False;User ID=$userNameSecret ;Password=$passwordSecret ;Connect Timeout=60;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False"
$sqlConnection.Open()

$param =$sqlConnection .Parameters.Add("@operation",[Data.SqlDbType]::nvarchar ,"@mode",[Data.SqlDbType]::nvarchar,"@LogToTable",[Data.SqlDbType]::bit )
Write-Output "DATABASE COMMAND SQLdatabase"
$sqlConnection.ExecuteNonQuery()
$sqlConnection.Close()
```

Comment: Check if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65391222/export-sql-query-output-using-powershell/65403924#65403924) helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use [Invoke-SqlCmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps) for this:

```
$operation  = 'index'
$mode       = 'smart'
$LogToTable = $true
$query = @"
exec MyProcedure $operation,$mode,$LogToTable
"@

Invoke-SqlCmd -Query $query -Database $database -ServerInstance $dataSource -Username $userNameSecret -Password $passwordSecret
```

Comment: This seems vulnerable to sql injection